# Change colour of toolStripLabel C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

I would like to change the colour of the label box - not just the text within the label. How would i do this?

`label.BackColor = Color.Coral;` (for instance) will change the colour of the text within the label.. rather than the background colour of the entire label box.

Also, if it matters, i'm using a toolStripContainer and ToolStrip. I used ToolStrip to create a label.... (i've used ForeColor in my code because using "BackColor" results in no change what so ever. Using ForeColor at least changes the colour of the font)

```
    private void labelEdit_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelEdit.ForeColor = Color.Coral;
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe that's your actual code, given the use of "Colour" instead of "Color". Please could you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Jon Skeet... my canadian-ness accidently happens to spell "color" as "colour" but yea.. my code is pretty much the same - with the exception of the spelling of the word..

Comment: Quite the reverse - I'm glad I asked, because now we've seen that it's not just the spelling of "Color" which is different. It's "fore" vs "back". See my answer.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of the one below, which has a potentially better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037406/why-doesnt-toolstriplabels-backcolor-property-change-during-design-time-or-run

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: It turns out the question is a bit of a red herring. Changing the `ForeColor` changes the text appropriately, but changing the `BackColor` does nothing, apparently.

EDIT: As per comments, it looks like you need to set [`ToolStrip.RenderMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.rendermode.aspx) to `ToolStripRenderMode.System` on your tool strip.

---

Now you've posted the actual code, the answer is obvious. You originally said you were using:

```
label.BackColour = Color.Coral;
```

You're actually using:

```
labelFile.ForeColor = Color.Coral;
```

Note "Fore" vs "Back". You wish to change the *background* colour... so you should be using

```
labelFile.BackColor = Color.Coral;
```

Comment: i've tried using BackColor, but it doesn't change anything at all, hence i put in ForeColor as it at least changes the font colour...

Comment: i've noticed that i can change "BackColor" for a button, but not a label... is there a way around this?

Comment: @BlueMonster: Well you should have said that before... if you're going to ask a question saying you're confused as to why the foreground colour is changing, and then you post code changing `ForeColor`, it's not clear what you've tried...

Comment: Sure, i'll be more clear in the future... after what i've described, do you know of a solution?

Comment: @BlueMonster: Unfortunately not offhand. Will edit my answer to help anyone else looking, but I'm not in a position right now to experiment :(

Comment: @Nalaka526 are you using a ToolStripContainer and a ToolStrip label as i mentioned in my Question?

Comment: @BlueMonster: This is why it would be useful if you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem :)

Comment: Lol, i thought i did? There is no way for me to show you that i'm using a ToolStipContainer as well as a ToolStrip label... is there?... But i did mention it in the Q

Comment: @BlueMonster Sorry, I wasn't using ToolStripContainer.... Add this line before changing the colour, toolStrip2.RenderMode= ToolStripRenderMode.System; This works.!!!

Comment: This where I learnt it from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winforms/thread/de357ebd-5315-4db4-a61d-de8d6a41a8d1

Comment: @BlueMonster Additional info : RenderMode can be changed from properties window